# Angular2 app not running in explorer 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a basic Angular2 app that's running fine in chrome, firefox but when I try to run it in explorer it gives me below error in console:

```
Error: (SystemJS) Access is denied.

    Error: Access is denied.

    at ZoneAwarePromise (file:///C:/Users/SACHDEVA/Desktop/Angular2_test/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:610:30)
    Error loading file:///C:/Users/SACHDEVA/Desktop/Angular2_test/app/boot.ts
```

dependencies are declared as:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/http.dev.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: You have to host your application on server to make it working

Comment: @PankajParkar Its working fine in Chrome and Firefox on my local machine, then what's the need to host it for explorer..?

Comment: I can see file protocol in your error, which is why I thought about that